# Expression to convert a Guid to a string

Tags: c#, mapping, expression

I need to copy all public properties of an object to another object of another type. The library [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) created by Jon Skeet contains the class PropertyCopy which is a perfect fit for what I need excepted for one thing. I have a property in the source object that need to be converted to another type in the target object (Guid => string).

Partial code from PropertyCopy:

```
if (!targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType))
{
    //My specific case
    if (sourceProperty.PropertyType == typeof(Guid) && targetProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        //Expression.Bind(targetProperty, [--Convert Guid to string expression??--]);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("...");
    }                              
}
```

So would it be possible to create an expression to bind the conversion of the source property to the target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below convert the Guid to string before binding it to the target property:

```
if (sourceProperty.PropertyType == typeof(Guid) && targetProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string))
{
    Expression callExpr = Expression.Call(Expression.Property(sourceParameter, sourceProperty), typeof(Guid).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { }));
    bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(targetProperty, callExpr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
Expression.Bind(targetProperty, (Expression<Func<Guid,string>>) (v=>v.ToString()));
```

would work...